# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los estilos se muestren en el startet kit de Laravel Jetstream?

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind, jetstream

Me aparece así el login y el registro en mi starter kit de Laravel Jetstream Livewire
[image: No cargan los estilos tailwind]

El problema, creo yo, viene que al momento de la instalación de Jetstream, al ejecutar el comando "npm run build", me aparece el siguiente error:  [image: no existe el script npm, aunque ya había ejecutado "npm install" anteriomente]

Estuve intentando solucionar el error y me topé con un video que explica lo que podría estar pasando https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gxxWTe3pVA . Pero al ejecutar "npm run dev", no se crea un servidor en Vite como sí pasó en el video, en vez, aparece lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que version de laravel es? Podrias compartir el  archivo `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que asegurarte que en el directorio principal de tu proyecto has usado `npm install` y exista en el archivo `package.json` lo siguiente:

```
"scripts": {
     "dev": "vite",
     "build": "vite build" 
     "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr" 
}
```

Entonces usarías los comandos: `npm run build` y `node bootstrap/ssr/ssr.js`. Si usas **inertia** para iniciar el lado del servidor `php artisan inertia:start-ssr`.

Adicionalmente, en el archivo `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
 
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

En este se pueden establecer diferentes variables, mas información: [laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#configuring-vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#configuring-vite)